Evaluating Tangent Vectors
I am looking at the Raychaudhuri equation which has a term like
$R_{ab} U^a U^b$,
where $U^a$ denotes the tangent vector to geodesics.  To evaluate this, I suppose one must choose a congruence of geodesics.  If we can choose a congruence of geodesics which is orthogonal to a hypersurface, does that mean that
$U^a = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}$
and hence that
$R_{ab} U^a U^b = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} R_{ii}$.
Or would it be
$R_{ab} U^a U^b = \nabla^2  R_{ii}$?

When you evaluate a tensor on a tangent vector you’re not differentiating the tensor. So neither of these is correct.

But I mean if $U^a$ is $\nabla^a$ for example, the nabla can go in front so it ends up being nabla^squared when contracted with the two indices of the tensor?

What do you even mean by $U^a$ is $\nabla^a$? It doesn’t make sense. Maybe you mean something like $(\partial_r)^a$, but still, that’s not like taking two $\partial_r$ derivatives, but rather “multiplying”. Anyway i suggest reviewing the basic definitions in the first few chapters of any book.

Can you advise what the tangent vector should be in this case?

The tangent vector to the geodesics, as you mentioned. It seems you do not understand what tangent vectors are and how to evaluate covariant tensors on tangent vectors. Please review the definitions; they really appear in the first few chapters of any GR/ differential geometry book.

Based on your notation (e.g. the use of 'a' and 'b' as indices) and question it seems as though you learned GR through Robert Wald's textbook, which defines vectors as directional derivatives and 1-forms as differentials/gradients.  The derivative quality of vectors only applies when applying vectors to hypothetical scalar "test functions", and when thinking about how vectors ought to transform when changing coordinate systems, not when "contracting" vectors with tensors or other vectors with the metric.  If you want, you could think of the contraction of a vector and a 1-form (or dual-vector) in the language of differentials in terms of the wedge product between a 1-form and an appropriate $(n-1)$-form (an appropriately weighted Hodge star of the vector or its dual.)
